# Django view without touching session and user

Tags: django, session

I have some views that don't need request.user at all, but as I see in django debug panel some database activity are performed in any case:

```
SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
24,124293785310734%
0,31    
    +   
SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
20,188323917137478%
0,26    
    +   
SELECT ••• FROM `django_session` WHERE (`django_session`.`session_key` = 'blahblah' AND `django_session`.`expire_date` > '2015-11-03 15:13:25')
23,804143126177024%
0,30    
Sel  Expl
    +   
SELECT ••• FROM `sys_user` WHERE `sys_user`.`id` = 1
```

Is there some decorator to disable SessionMiddleware and AuthenticationMiddleware?

Comment: There isn't. However, both `request.user` and `request.session` are loaded lazily. If you see database queries, it's because the data is used by some part of your application.

Comment: This blog explains how to exclude views http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/08/31/django-exclude-some-views-from-middleware.html

Comment: Thanks knbk, seems like I found the reason why SQL was performed - I used RequestContext in this view (that have no sense), and thats why lazy objects was activated. Now only SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0 is running